# Excel If Or Statement not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of data and I wanted to identify the swap candidate based on two criteria:

1. If first column < 0.5 OR
2. If first column divided by second column < 10.

And here's my formula `=IF(OR(E2<0.5,(E2/F2)<=10),"Swap Candidate"," ")`

(The first and second column are in column E and F in the workbook). But the function doesn't work as it should. It instead returns all values as true while it's not. For example in the highlighted cell.

[image]

I also ran the formula evaluate for the highlighted cell. And it shows FALSE after evaluating the OR statement but then return the value if true.
[image]

The numbers are stored in the correct format. So I don't get what's going on with it. Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: Are automatic calculations on in your workbook?

Comment: It works correctly for me.  This sounds dumb, but have you tried closing excel and reopening the workbook?

Comment: This is a long shot (and really silly), but, you don't have the number formatting for the formula cell set to `@"Swap Candidate"` do you?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I just tried reopen it, and checked my calculation in on automatic. Still doesn't work. And I didn't changed the number formatting in the @"Swap Candidate" column, it's under General. I guess it must be something wrong with my computer...

Comment: Do you have any conditional formatting?

Comment: @qshngv Might have to link the spreadsheet somehow in order for us to fully reproduce the error

Comment: What's the exact formula in the yellow highlighted "Swap Candidate" cell? Could be that you copy/pasted or dragged the formula in a way that the relative cell references didn't propagate properly.

Comment: Hi all, I didn't change any formatting in the workbook and the formula was referencing correctly. I found that if I paste the data in a new workbook, the formula works. So must be something with the particular workbook. Anyways, I've got around this problem by pasting the data back. Still no idea why it occurs though...

Answer (score 1):

Check if your workbook are calculating, press `F9` to force you workbook to calculate

**Edit 1:**

I tried input your formula in my Excel(PT-BR) and works, look:

[image]

**Edit 2:**

See if your workbook aren't calculating, click in "Formulas" and check if "Calculate Options" are "Manual" or "Automatic Except for Daata Tables", if one of options are checked, change to "Automatic"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this was so annoying figured I'd post what worked for me...

My `OR` statement was structured as follows:

```
=OR(FIND("**",[@Status])=1,[@SortOrder]=1,[@Status]="Active",[@Status]="Focus Mode")
```

The error was occurring when the `OR` function evaluated the `FIND()` function first - if "**" was not present in the "Status" column, the function returned a #VALUE! error instead of proceeding to evaluate the rest of the `OR` statement. (This is why, when I put `=[@Status]="Focus Mode"` in a separate column, it evaluated correctly as TRUE, but after embedding it in the `OR` statement, it returned #VALUE!)

To fix this error I adjusted the formula as follows:

```
=OR(IFERROR(FIND("**",[@Status])=1,FALSE),[@SortOrder]=1,[@Status]="Active",[@Status]="Focus Mode")
```